# If first condition satisfies perform it, otherwise second condition in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to take Employee by status from table. I have 2 statuses, If an employee has **A** condition take that row, otherwise take **P** status row with maximum **oper_day** It looks like below:

**Table**

```
---------------------------------------------------
id  |  emp_code  | name    | status   | oper_day  |
--------------------------------------------------
1   |  164094    | John    | P        | 2020-10-02 |
2   |  164094    | John    | P        | 2020-10-09 |
3   |  164094    | John    | A        | 2020-10-10 |
4   |  145890    | Mike    | P        | 2020-10-05 |
```

My result should look like below

```
--------------------------------
id  |  emp_code  | name    | status   | oper_day  |
--------------------------------------------------
1   |  164094    | John    | A        | 2020-10-10 |
2   |  145890    | Mike    | P        | 2020-10-05 |
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_code ORDER BY status, oper_day DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT id, emp_code, name, status, oper_day  
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The logic here is that should an employee have a status `A` record, it would be assigned the first row number, since `A` sorts before `P`.  Otherwise, a `P` status record would be chosen.  We choose the more recent record per employee in case of multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation functions with `KEEP( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ... )`:

```sql
SELECT MAX( id ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY status ASC, oper_day DESC ) AS id,
       emp_code,
       MAX( name ),
       MIN( status ) AS status,
       MAX( oper_day ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY status ) AS oper_day
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       emp_code
```

Which., for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, emp_code, name, status, oper_day ) AS
SELECT 1, 164094, 'John', 'P', DATE '2020-10-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 164094, 'John', 'P', DATE '2020-10-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 164094, 'John', 'A', DATE '2020-10-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 145890, 'Mike', 'P', DATE '2020-10-05' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | EMP_CODE | MAX(NAME) | STATUS | OPER_DAY           
> -: | -------: | :-------- | :----- | :------------------
>  4 |   145890 | Mike      | P      | 2020-10-05 00:00:00
>  3 |   164094 | John      | A      | 2020-10-10 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=63357a39cbf6e6cf42397239cdfdda5c)*